# How to deal with this HR person

Tags: human-resources

I do not have a lot of experience doing interviews.

I applied for this job and this HR person said she would tell me if the role is available or not.

Its been about a month and I followed up with her and she said she is in a meeting and will contact me after she is finished.

After 1 week I sent her a message and asked her if there would be a good time for her that we talk.

Now is another week and she hasn't responded yet. (all communication through whatsupp)

Is this normal?

I can provide more context if need be.

I will add some information in the hope it helps someone:
from reading several specialized job websites it said its a good thing to follow up around 2-4 times with 1-2 weeks apart. It shows interest and it shows enthusiasm.

Comment: Forget this one. Either they don't want you or already offered the job to someone else. Next time, get a referral from an internal employee.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: although Whassapp is very popular even with business in some regions, I would probably dismiss and forget about any HR that uses it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The role probably isn't available and they are just unwilling to say no.**

It isn't all that unusual when a job is no longer available. Saying no to people is unpleasant, so plenty are unwilling to do it. Many people also do not react well to being told no, so silence or false promises can reduce anguish.

You are very unlikely to get the job. Move on to something else.

Comment: the problem is that they said the role itself does not exist even tho they had it posted. she said that some websites change the role name sometimes. i sent her the email from their own company showing the role. then she said she will get back to me. its not that if the role has or has not been filled.

Comment: @proger lots of job postings are just there to see if a star walks in or as a formality for someone already hired.

Answer (score 7):

After three failed attempts take the hint and stop asking.

The fact that no one has contacted you in nearly two months is your answer. Unfortunately, not everyone at HR is polite enough or has the time to inform each and every candidate whether they have been hired or have passed the first hurdle.

Comment: actually she did respond once with salutation but with no information as to my situation....

Comment: @proger she politely acknowledged your WhatsApp message but didn't give you the answer you were looking for.  It was only a  salutation, stop wasting your time and move on.